# RegularExpression attribute for my domain object of type string has strange behavior

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, regex, validation, attributes

I'm developing an MVC 4 ASP.NET application with Razor view engine. I have a property in view called 'Title' and has set its metadata like this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[\p{L}\p{N}\s\,\،\-\(\)\u200C]*$", ErrorMessage = "Some error message")]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

In view, as soon as I start typing any character in corresponding textbox, it shows the validation message. This is the razor view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The client-side validator is using javascript, so the regex needs to be in javascript-specific syntax.

According to [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html), the `\p{...}` constructs are not supported.

You might be able to replace `\p{L}\p{N}` with `\w`, depending on your target character set.